# Problema con base de datos MySQL para inicio de sesión

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio

Intento hacer un inicio de sesión usando c# y MySQL pero me sale este error **Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()** ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo? y gracias por la ayuda
lo que intento es que despues de capturar el usuario y contraseña el sistema valide si coinciden con el de la base de datos para que lo deje acceder al software, posteriormente debe validar si es administrador, vendedor, etc. y así mismo le de el menú o las opciones correspondientes

```
            MySqlConnection Conexion = conexion.conex();
            Conexion.Open();
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
            comando.Connection = Conexion;
            comando.CommandText = ("Select usuario,contraseña from userr where usuario= '" + user +"' ");
            MySqlDataReader reg = comando.ExecuteReader();
            int val = 0;

            try { 
            if (user.Equals(reg["usuario"].ToString())&& pass.Equals(reg["contrasña"].ToString()))
            {
               
                timer1.Enabled = true;
               for (int i = 0; i <100; i++) { 
                        posicion = 1;
                    }
                    val = 0;


            }
            else
            {
                val = 1;
            }
            if (val == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("USUARIO O PASSWORD INCORRECTOS");
                txtpass.Text = "";
                txtusuario.Text = "";
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }

            Conexion.Close();}`


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SZA9.png
```

Comment: Puede ser un error en su SQL?  Y donde dice el nombre del base de datos?

Comment: Es un reader.. si haces exactamente lo que dice el error, se soluciona...

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, siguiendo el error, no puedes acceder a alguna columna si no lees el resultado primero. Para esto ejecuta `reg .Read()` después del `MySqlDataReader reg = comando.ExecuteReader();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes aplicar hacer esto en este bloque de codigo

```
while (reg.Read())
{ 
 if (user.Equals(reg["usuario"].ToString())&& 
 pass.Equals(reg["contrasña"].ToString()))
 {
   timer1.Enabled = true;
   for (int i = 0; i <100; i++) 
   { posicion = 1;}
   val = 0;
 }else
 {
  val = 1;
  }}
```

Comment: Por qué este código resuelve la pregunta? Procura siempre explicar qué hace el código que sugieres y cómo debería usarse.